# direct machines with HTTP messages through browsers

Tags: browser, lan, http

I'am running a ventilation system in my home. It gets accessed through LAN with a browser. I'm curious, how is it possible to permanently change a machine's state through browser using just HTTP messages?

It obviously runs a web server, but I haven't been able to understand how a web server controls the actual computer. Perhaps there is a middle man between a socket and a web server that can read http messages and makes decisions, and after doing so, it forwards that http message to web server which in turn visualises the changes in the response message?

[image]

Comment: Is that a self-made ventilation system? Do you have access to its internals? And please elaborate your question a bit ...

Comment: Nope, a bought one. Since I own it, I guess I could open it and is its hardware. What should I look for? Basically I just type in the browser the current LAN address (such as 192.168.1.55) and the page with controls opens. I can than set the air flow of the ventilation etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP offers some methods to interact with a host OS using the `exec()` and `shell_exec()` methods.

- `exec` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
- `shell_exec` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

The functions allow PHP to run (and receive output from) the command which can either be outputted to the page for the user or used as input to other PHP processes.

Alternatively, your ventilation system may use a Java, C, C++ system that PHP interacts with that's doing everything in the background on its behalf.